# combobox value hide another combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I have 2 combobxes  .. combobox1 and combobox2

combobox1 is hidden by default

I want if the value of combobox2 is null or empty combobox2 be hidden from the form and show combobox1

I tried this approach but didn't work

```
  private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            comboBox1.Visible = true;
            comboBox2.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

how to make it right

thanks in advance

Comment: Double-check your logic in the `if` statement. You've got the condition backwards (hiding control when it has a selection).

Comment: grant .. thanks for your answer .. I don't get what u mean .. can u show me in the code how ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated before by Grant your if statement is wrong.

a better one would be

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedValue == null)
{
comboBox1.Visible = true;
comboBox2.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a more elegant logic it would be like this. And this switches to true or false already.

```
bool hasValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text) && comboBox2.SelectedIndex > -1;
comboBox2.Visible = hasValue;
comboBox1.Visible = !hasValue;
```